# Error: Shell class SyncAccessTokenShell could not be found

Tags: cakephp, shell, cakephp-2, console

Minha aplicação é cake 2.4.4, está hospedado na Amazon.
Antes o servidor era apache, porém agora migramos para o nginx para melhor performance. Como já era de se esperar vários problemas ocorreram (normal), mais um deles que está me dando um certa dor de cabeça é o console

Comando a ser executado no terminal:

```
../app/Console/cake SyncAccessToken syncAccounts
Error: Shell class SyncAccessTokenShell could not be found.
#0 /srv/www/htdocs/app.atentools.com/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(198): ShellDispatcher->_getShell('SyncAccessToken')
#1 /srv/www/htdocs/app.atentools.com/lib/Cake/Console/ShellDispatcher.php(66): ShellDispatcher->dispatch()
#2 /srv/www/htdocs/app.atentools.com/app/Console/cake.php(36): ShellDispatcher::run(Array)
#3 {main}
```

Ele fala que a classe "SyncAccessToken "não foi encontrada, porém ele printa a classe toda antes de dar o erro o.0

Já pesquisei bastante porem o erro persiste
Alguém arrisca um palpite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema não estava no ngnix!

Resolvi indo no php.ini, em open_short_tags coloquei on, pois estava off

open_short_table permite abrir arquivos php utilizando apenas

O que acontecia é que o arquivo da classe era encontrada mas não era processada, o servidor entendia como se fosse um arquivo de texto